# Hiding the port and encrypt http to https

Tags: windows, http, dns, ip, port

I set up a website running on a local a.tomcat server on a specific port on a windows 10 machine. I forwarded the port and used DuckDns to register my ip so its easier to access. My question would be what should I do to change it to from

> http://mywebsite.duckdns.org:portnumber

to just

> http://mywebsite.duckdns.org or https://mywebsite.duckdns.org

would be even better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a website on Netlify. It creates an automatic https:// for your site. However, it would be a .com rather than an .org. If you just want to get the https certificate, just go to https://www.sslforfree.com/.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the external port forwarding from portnumber to 80 because when you didn't specify a port number it will auto go to port 80. 
Now i just have to figure out a way to encrypt the thing to https and I'm good to go.